# tgz file is included in git push command, but cannot find it in repo (not tracked)

Tags: git, github

I have a large `.tgz` file that's being tracked for some reason in a git repo. But I can't seem to find it.

If I do:

```
git rm --cached *.tgz
```

no files match. But when I push to a remote repo, I am seeing this:

```
Writing objects: 100% (22674/22674), 190.82 MiB | 217.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 22674 (delta 15663), reused 14939 (delta 10079)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (15663/15663), completed with 97 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 37cd0aa0f9604277b7c54e1b9b6951a5
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File mongodb-version2/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.12.tgz is 111.31 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/ORESoftware/cdt-now.git
 ! [remote rejected]   dev -> dev (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ORESoftware/cdt-now.git'
```

does anyone know what the hell might be going on?

Comment: looks like it's not in the current branch, but is tracked somewhere in the repo history

Comment: It's in whatever branch you're pushing. It looks like maybe it's not at the path you expect, or it could exist in an earlier commit. What does `git log mongodb-version2/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.12.tgz` give? (Note that your `git rm` command's `*.tgz` argument is processed by your shell, not Git. It will not match `mongodb-version2/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.12.tgz`.)

Comment: And anyway it's not enough to remove the file from the last commit. You need to  [remove the file from the entire commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository).